# angular cli installation fails on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

After installing npm and node, I'm trying to install `Angular-cli` using this command line :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Yet it gives me a permission error :

```
stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
```

The obvious thing to do in this case is to precede the command with `sudo` so that it will be executed as a superuser but this seems to take the eternity.

Is there any other option that may save me some time struggling with the installation?

Comment: See the official guide by NPM on how to resolve this: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

After one day running, Sudo did the work for me. So those who are having the same issue, just do the installation as a superuser.